# # cursor to split the column #

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table

```
WS_ID   WS_WEBPAGE_ID   WS_SPONSORS_ID  WS_STATUS   WS_CREATEDTS
2   3             2          N        2012-06-07 15:32:00
3   3        3           N              2012-06-07 15:37:00
4   3        4           Y             2012-06-07 15:41:00
5   1        1           Y              2012-06-07 16:05:00
6   2        1           Y              2012-06-07 16:05:00
7   2        4           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
8   4        1           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
9   1        3           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
10  1        2           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
11  1        4           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
12  2        3           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
13  2        3           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
14  2        1           Y             2012-06-07 16:05:00
24706   3             8,7,9,5,5     NULL          NULL
```

I wrote a cursor and calling the split function in to that cursor to split the last record

```
Declare @splitc varchar(250)
Declare splitcursor cursor for
select ws_sponsors_id from dbo.TBL_WD_SPONSORS 
open splitcursor
fetch next from splitcursor into @splitc
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
  print '@splitcursor'

--select * from dbo.Comma_Split(@ws_sponsors_id,',')
select dbo.Comma_Split(ws_sponsors_id,',') from dbo.TBL_WD_SPONSORS where ws_id = 24706

--select * from dbo.TBL_WD_SPONSORS where WS_SPONSORS_ID in(select * from dbo.Comma_Split(ws_sponsors_id,','))

    fetch next from splitcursor into @splitc
  end
  close splitcursor
  deallocate splitcursor
```

And I am getting the Error

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Comma_Split", or the name is ambiguous.

```
 WS_ID  WS_WEBPAGE_ID  WS_SPONSORS_ID  WS_STATUS  WS_CREATEDTS


 24706    3              8,7,9,5,5        NULL     NULL
```

But I need the Output

```
WS_ID        WS_WEBPAGE_ID      WS_SPONSORS_ID       WS_STATUS      WS_CREATEDTS
24706             3                 8                  NULL           NULL
24707             3                 7                  NULL           NULL
24708             3                 9                  NULL           NULL
24709             3                 5                  NULL           NULL
24710             3                 5                  NULL           NULL
```

How to get the Output

Help me out.

Comment: Because the formatting is non-existent, it's hard to tell, but is this any different [from your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948396/how-to-split-the-column-values-using-stored-procedure)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not re-architect your tables so you only have 1 value entered in your WS_SPONSORS_ID column so it's a foreign-key relationship, then you wouldn't have to do this split function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function you're trying to use does not exist on the database you're running it on. For instance, try this and you'll get the same error:

```
SELECT dbo.This_Function_Most_Certainly_Doesnt_Exist('Unless you''re trying to break my example.')
```

This will prove if it is there or not so that you don't have to take my word for it. Run this on the database that you're  running your cursor based query on:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES R WHERE R.ROUTINE_NAME = 'Comma_Split'
```

If you don't get any rows back, that is because the function doesn't exist there. Either you're on the wrong database, the wrong version, you need to run the CREATE FUNCTION on it, or something like that.

EDIT: By the way, as for how to solve the actual problem: Don't use a cursor. A cursor is used as a form of iteration over a data result set. In your cursor you're selecting the value for a single row:

```
select dbo.Comma_Split(ws_sponsors_id,',') from dbo.TBL_WD_SPONSORS where ws_id = 24706
```

The way you have it, you'd call that function, on that row, once for every row on the table. Here's a good example of a split function: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/06/best-split-udf-function-with-delimeter.html

Using that you would just need to write:

```
SELECT dbo.fnStringSplitter(ws_sponsors_id, ',') FROM dbo.TBL_WT_SPONSORS WHERE ws_id = 24706
```